# How to upload files on one website using another one

Tags: php

I am having two websites one is `A` and another one is `B` I have an image uploading form in `A` which allows user to upload files.A also has a database recording path of image file is actually has to go to the `B` How to do this?. i am owning both the websites. Any idea?.

Comment: You can Use CURL for this .

Comment: Do you have documentation regarding this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this by using PHP FTP
see below code-

```
$connection = ftp_connect($server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, $mode);

    if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection);
```

Comment: consider i uploaded a file from a form but in the place of source what i have to receive from the form?.

Comment: source will be  $_FILES["your_file_name_given_in_form"]["tmp_name"];

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.5.0', '>='))
    {
        $postData['file'] = new CURLFile($fileData['tmp_name'], $fileData['type'] ,$fileData['name']);
    }
    else
    {
        $postData['file'] = '@'.$fileData['tmp_name'];
        $postData['file_info']['name'] = $fileData['name'];
    }

    $url = 'http://your-site.com/';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $output= curl_exec($ch);

    if ($output === false)
    {
        //handle the error
    }

    curl_close ($ch);
```

Note: If you have php 5.5 and higher it is recommended to use CURLFile.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help.

```
<?php
$target="http://youraddress.tld/example/upload.php";

# http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php

// Create a CURLFile object / procedural method
$cfile = curl_file_create('resource/test.png','image/png','testpic'); // try adding

// Create a CURLFile object / oop method
#$cfile = new CURLFile('resource/test.png','image/png','testpic'); // uncomment and use if the upper procedural method is not working.

// Assign POST data
$imgdata = array('myimage' => $cfile);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15','Referer: http://someaddress.tld','Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // stop verifying certificate
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // enable posting
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $imgdata); // post images
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // if any redirection after upload
$r = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

*[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php#115569)*

Comment: In this no authentication is required from another server?